# Is there a verb counterpart to "pair" when bringing together three things

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, triple-thrice

The word *pair* is used both as a noun

> a pair of gloves

and a verb

> a cardigan paired with a matching shirt

I believe the matching noun for three things is *"trio"*, but is there a corresponding verb used for bringing together three things?

---

To clarify, I'm looking for a word that applies to combining **exactly three different** things. Not less, not more.

Comment: Just the hypernym _combine_. (and perhaps synonyms).

Comment: You can always pair the cardigan and matching shirt with sweatpants. Now three things are combined.

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking for a word that applies to combining exactly three things. Not less, not more.

Comment: You don't want 'treble' (noun and verb, just as 'pair')?

Comment: @JEL AFAIK, *"treble"* is just another form of *"triple"* as a verb. i.e. *multiply by three*, not *combine three things*

Comment: I suppose the evidence is inconclusive, especially relying only on dictionaries, rather than uses. See answers at [Is there a difference between “treble” and “triple”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44125/is-there-a-difference-between-treble-and-triple). I suspect use-cases are going to produce more immediate comprehension with either 'triple' or 'treble' than 'intrine' (as verb with the sense of "combine three" rather than "increase by three"). As adjective formed from the past participle, either 'tripled' and 'trebled', "combined 3 similar things", is the English lexical item.

Comment: @JEL that means I need to clarify once more. I want something that combines exactly three **different** things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **intrine**, though don't expect most people to know it.

English provides a lot of options for grouping more than two items: *group*, *combine*, *match*, *assemble*, *bring together*. Whereas a *pair* has a lot of specific associations in English (couples, card games, chromosomes, body parts), *trios* are rarer, and bringing three items together (rather than two or four) is rarer still.

Rarely, people do turn *trio* into a verb, though in a specific sense referring to playing against an opponent in a group of three. (Example from a [Final Fantasy XI encyclopedia](https://ffxiclopedia.fandom.com/wiki/Talk:Martinet), where it is used interchangeably with *solo* and *duo*.) So verbing *trio* to mean *combining* would possibly lead to confusion.

A more established word would be **[intrine](https://oed.com/view/Entry/98697)**. It's rare; the only example in the OED is from a translation of Dante's *Divine Comedy*, III.xiii.84:

> The Love which with them is **intrined** [l. 57, l'Amor che in lor s'intrea].

Here is the excerpt more fully, from the [Princeton Dante Project](https://dante.princeton.edu/cgi-bin/dante/campuscgi/mpb/GetCantoSection.pl?LANG=2&INP_POEM=Par&INP_SECT=13&INP_START=53&INP_LEN=15):

> For that living Light, which so streams forth
>
> from its shining Source that it neither parts from it
>
> nor from the Love that is **intrined** with them,
>
> of its own goodness gathers its won shining,
>
> as though it were a mirror, in nine subsistences,
>
> and yet eternally endures as one.

So the Light, the Source, and the Love (names for the three parts of the Christian Holy Trinity) are *intrined*. The word is virtually preserved from Dante's own use (the reflexive verb used is *s'intrea* - roughly *puts itself in three*), a verb that Dante coined in Italian in order to represent the Trinity:

> Yet, a third variety [of neologism] turns numbers into verbs, as *incinquarsi, **intrearsi**, immillarsi,* and *internarsi*. Again, numbers are concrete abstractions, but Dante confounds their numerical stability, by making them reflexive verbs, numbers multiplying themselves, pointing to infinity. This is particularly appropriate for the mystery of God's infinity and trinity. (B. D. Schildgen, "[Dante's Neologisms in the Paradiso and the Latin Rhetorical Tradition.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40166383)" *Dante Studies* 107, 1989.)

This may be the closest to what you are looking for ("a corresponding verb for bringing together three things"), though it is both a specific and rare usage compared to *pair*.

Comment: So doesn't OED caveat 'intrine' (or is it too divine to be obsolete?)

Comment: The OED calls it *rare*, but does not call it obsolete. At the very least, more recent translations of Dante still use the word.

Comment: That was an interesting exercise, but given that its only appearance in the English language is as a translation from Dante's 1300s Italian coinage, it seems inadvisable to use it.

Comment: Or, perhaps we're bringing *intrine* back; we're bringing *intrine* back...:)

Comment: that's the sort of thing I was looking for :)

Comment: Can I go crazy and ask if there's a tri-fold version of *"both"*?

Comment: @FeliniusRex [count me in](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/edgerunner/elm-tuple-trio/latest/Tuple-Trio#intrine)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the verb ***to match***: meaning:

> to harmonize with:

- the jacket matched the pants and the shirt.

Comment: Far too broad. Exactly three items (or the question becomes trivial).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - there is no such verb AFAIK. Match can sole the problem.

Comment: Maybe I should have made that requirement clear. Three and only exactly three. :)